# How to add an interceptor to another interceptor with nestJS?

Tags: nestjs

I would like to add the result of a global interceptor to a router interceptor.

The goal is to add copyrights to every accesss  to my api.

I have 2 interceptors.
The '**local**' one is on a route:

```
provider: "opendatafrance",
};
var geocoder = NodeGeocoder(options);
@Injectable()
export class PlaceInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  async intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Promise<Observable<any>> {

    var monaddress = context.switchToHttp().getRequest().body
    const geocodeResult = from(geocoder.geocode(monaddress));
    const geocoded = await lastValueFrom(geocodeResult);
  context.switchToHttp().getRequest().body = {
    address: monaddress,
    geocoded: geocoded
}
    return next.handle().pipe(
       map(value => {
        return {
          ...value,
          geoCoder: geocoded
        }
      })
      )
  }

}
```

The **global** one is:

```
@Injectable()
export class CopyrightsInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    return next.handle().pipe(
      map(value => {
        return {
          tt: "All rights reserved"        
        }
      })
    );
  }
```

The result is that swagger returns the text coming from the global interceptor whilst the returning data of the intercepted route is correctly saves into the database.

I would like to add the copyrights text to every result.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `map` in your `CopyrightsInterceptor` to be

```js
map((value) => ({ ...value, tt: 'All rights reserved' }))
```

This will take the return from the `PlaceInterceptor` and merge it with the `tt` from the `CopyrightsInterceptor` as you're looking to do